# Count "things" result of calculated column in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerbi, powerpivot

I have a question related to a calculated column in Excel pivot. I have detail data below :

[image]

I can make summary data GDP per region with those number and I will make new column called `performance` with these rules:

- with GDP > 1000

  - then "excellent region"
  - else "developing region"

The question is: how to make `performance` column with calculated column in the single pivot table?

[image]

Final result :

- Developing region = 1
- Excellent region = 2

Thank you everyone,

Answer (score 0):

As there are a few things to go through, I'll do it step by step (reference to the attached image):

Referenced image starts from column `A`. Colmns `A` to `C` holds the table in your question

Column `E` just holds the region name. Column `F` holds the total for each region. This is achieved by using the following formula for region `A` in row 13: `=SUMIF($A$13:$A$18, "A", $C$13:$C$18)`. Same formula is repeated for each region (replacing the regions name. i.e. for region "B" the formula is `=SUMIF($A$13:$A$18, "B", $C$13:$C$18)`)

Column `G` uses following formula to calculate region status for each region: `=IF(F13>1000,"excellent region","developing region")` (for each row, change the referenced cell. i.e. F13 for region `A`, F14 for region `B` and F15 for region `C`)

Column `I` calculates the count of region types using following formula for **Developing region** in cell `I13`: `="Developing region = " & COUNTIF($G$13:$G$15, "developing region")`. And following formula for **Excellent region** in cell `I14`: `="Excellent region = " & COUNTIF($G$13:$G$15, "excellent region")`

You can now use Range `E12:F15` to create your pivot table.

**Note**: please don't forget to change your range depending on where your data is and where you want it to be displayed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select the pivot table > Analyze > Fields, Items & Sets > Calculated Field....

Then enter `performance` as your name and the formula `=IF(GDP>1000,1,2)`

[image: Input]

Which will give you:

[image: Results]